# IIS 7 - IIS 6 Problem

Tags: vbscript, iis-6

I'm trying to run this script to assign Application Pool to web site running under IIS 6

```
Set oWebAdmin = GetObject("winmgmts:root\WebAdministration")
Set oSite = oWebAdmin.Get("Site.Name='Site'")
oSite.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPool = "NewAppPool"
oSite.Put_
```

This script can't run under IIS 6... Is there is something wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, root\WebAdministration is new in IIS7, it can't work in IIS6. Use ADSI.

Comment: I am getting 8004100E error on iis 7. Any hints? If u wish I can post my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objVirtualDirectory = GetObject( "IIS://localhost/" + strSitePath + "/ROOT" )


' Assign the Pool to the Site
objVirtualDirectory.AppPoolID = strAppPool
objVirtualDirectory.AppFriendlyName = "me app"
objVirtualDirectory.Put_()
```